# After TeXstudio update (3.0) BibLaTeX does not work anymore: Error File `biblatex.sty' not found. \usepackage

Tags: biblatex, citing, miktex, texstudio

I am currently writing a term paper. I did start it around march and let it rest until now.
The problem I am facing is that I updated my Texstudio so that I have the newest version, but somehow now my biblatex does not work anymore. I did not change anything on the syntax, it just does not work anymore. Not only in this case but in every latex document i own...

I tried to reinstall MikTex, I also installed manually the biblatex package on the MikTex Console However, it still gives me an error if I try to run the script.

The error: File `biblatex.sty' not found. \usepackage

Here is a short example of my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\title{TITLE}

\usepackage[style=apa,
backref=true,   
%backend=biber, 
hyperref=true]
{biblatex} 
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\bibliography{Bib.bib}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
\section{Introduction}

\autocite{key}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Also, even though it says that biblatex is missing, autocite works in that sense that I start to type \autocite and I get the keys proposed.

I tried many different kinds of citation until now, but nothing works. Everything becomes this error...

Do I have to install something else?

Comment: The first thing you should do it stopping to install or change things. Try to find some clue what is wrong. Try to compile on a command line to exclude that texstudio is the problem.

Comment: If you are not familiar with compiling from the command line you may be interested in https://texwelt.de/fragen/3461/wie-kompiliere-ich-in-der-eingabeaufforderung-im-terminal (the link is in German, but since your code suggests your document is in German I'm assuming you can read that)